# how to send messages to the channel that command was sent discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

so I made a bot command in discord.py , which user types the command , and then gives some inputs to it , then the code places the inputs to a embed and sends it. I want a method to be able to send the result to the same channel that command was sent.
I've read about sending messages , but many say there needs to be channel id to send a message, but I want it to send it to the same channel that command was run.
can you help me out with this?

**EDIT**
here's the code :

```
@bot.command(name="fban")
async def fban(ctx):
    # This will make sure that the response will 
    # only be registered if the following
    # conditions are met:
    def check(msg):
        return msg.author == ctx.author and msg.channel == ctx.channel
    msg = await bot.wait_for("message", check=check)
    outmsg = msg.content.lower()
    username = outmsg.splitlines()[0]
    reason = outmsg.splitlines()[1]

    fake_ban_embed = discord.Embed(title="{username} was 
    banned.",description="Reason : {reason}")
    fake_ban_embed.set_thumbnail(url='https://imgur.com/FkqtqE8')

    await message.reply(embed=fake_ban_embed)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command is automatically sent to the same channel as the user calls it (unless you specify a channel to send a message)

```py
@bot.command()
async def mycommand(ctx: commands.Context, arg1: str, ...):
  await ctx.send("...")  # the msg "..." will be sent to the same channel

  embed = discord.Embed(title="...", description="...")  # create an embed
  await ctx.send(embed=embed)  # embed will be sent to the same channel

  await ctx.reply("...")  # reply to the same channel

  # specify a channel to send sth
  channel = bot.get_channel(CHANNEL_ID)  # this will work if you cache channels  during startup
  # otherwise use "channel = await bot.fetch_channel(CHANNEL_ID)" but this is an API call
  await channel.send("...", embed=embed)  # this will send to the channel you specified
```

Comment: i have a question , is ctx a self defined object?

Comment: @ParsaAd it's the context. Here is the [docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Context)

Answer (score 0):

I am using this in my discord bot for commands:

```
@bot.command
  async def command(ctx)
    await ctx.send("This message sent to the same channel where command is written")
```